# MQTT topic limitations with AWS IoT

Tags: mqtt, iot, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

I have a AWS IoT solution, in which ten thousands of devices send data per second to a MQTT topic. i.e 10,000 messages published per second. Messages will be sent to AWS Kinesis via IoT rule.

So is there any limitation, saying that we can publish up to a certain number of messages per second to a MQTT topic.

When we tried with higher number of messages per second, after a certain limit (700 messages per second) messages were lost and not stored in Kinesis.

Having multiple topics to publish data, will resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no limitation in the MQTT standard. This would be a limitation of the platform/broker. What does Amazon say???

Answer (score 2):

There is some limitations that you can find here: [AWS IoT Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_iot)

I think you may be reaching this limit:

> Publish requests per second per account
>   9000 per second per account (inbound publish requests - max. 3000 per second, outbound publish requests - max. 6000 per second).
>
> Inbound publish requests count for all the messages that the message broker processes before routing the messages to the subscribed clients or the rules engine. For example, **a single message published** on $aws/things/device/shadow/update topic **can result in publishing three additional messages** to $aws/things/device/shadow/update/accepted, $aws/things/device/shadow/update/documents, $aws/things/device/shadow/delta topics. In this case, **AWS IoT counts those as 4 inbound publish requests towards this limit**. However, a single message to an unreserved topic like "a/b" is counted only as a single inbound publish request.